# pandoc docx to md with images conversion problem

Tags: linux, bash, pandoc

pandoc docx to md batch conversion with images but it's not correctly converting.
here is my command

```
for item in *.docx; do pandoc "$item" -o "${item%.docx}.md" --extract-media=. "$item" ; done
```

[document link(dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2im5sokgp8otltf/AABNLwTkM_ugGwwvPW6ybeR8a?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the soultion [docx2md.sh](https://gist.github.com/jesperronn/ff5764274b3642bc7f2f#file-docx2md-sh)
code edited to `pandoc -f docx -t markdown -w gfm --extract-media="." -o "$1.md" "../$1.docx"` avoid img tag and name conflict. Run

```
for item in *.docx; do file=${item::-5}; ./docx2md.sh "$file" ; done
```